Unresolved external symbol in C with source and header files
I just started coding in C. I downloaded the C/C++ extension, ran VScode through command prompt... Everything was, so far, working perfeclty. But, I tried working with source and header file, and I got an error that I can't  get rid of.
Here are my three files:
main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "area.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) // Équivalent de int main()
{
    double result;
    result = areaRectangle(2.0,3.0);
    printf("%f", result);
    return 0;
    
}


area.h
#ifndef area_h
#define area_h
#include <stdio.h>

double areaRectangle(double , double);
#endif


area.c
#include "area.h"

double areaRectangle(double height, double lenght){
    return height*lenght;
}

And then, here is the error code that I get when running main.c (I can't copy paste the code since it's in french, but i'll do my best translating it):
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _areaRectangle called in function _main

I don't know where does the problem comes from... and I checked multiple times where does the error occurs...
Thanks for your help :)

This usually means you're not linking in the object file (area.obj in this case).

"running main.c" -> show your command for compiling it. I suspect you just didn't compile area.c

Thanks for your anwser y'all. @500-InternalServerError, I tried checking this file, but I can't read it in VScode, is it supposed to be edited manually ?

@julaine, I do not use any command: just the "run" button in VScode (which is apparently "linked" to the compiler)

area.obj would be generated by the compiler as a result of compiling area.c. I'm sorry, I can't help you with how to do c in VScode - I use that only for Angular stuff, but I can gather from the number of questions that it's not super friendly to c/cpp developers.

Each source file in a C program must be compiled to an object file. Then the objects are linked to create the executable. Your error is on the link step.

Learn how to compile your program without the IDE. Only then teach the IDE how to do it. You won't understand the IDE-configurations if you don't understand the steps it should take, and you won't be able to build the program on another machine (co-worker, server, user-machine...) if you need an IDE to do it. This isn't command-line-elitism, this is pragmatism.

Thank's for your great anwser, I will stick with that :) I thought that it was easier in every points to use IDE to compile. I'll use another compiler now !

@Z1scko unfortunately with C, understanding the compilation process is to some level necessary for programming. For most other languages you just have a single build-tool/project structure that is considered standard for new projects on any operating system and you can just stick to that and forget the details. But C is a mess, in many ways, and building is one of the pain-points.

Thank's @julaine, I hope that my motivation is strong enough to learn all of that :)

As various others have mentioned/alluded to , most likely your command to build in VS does not include all the files needed to be compiled.
(I don't have VS so can't give/show you how to fix that, but should be trivial), however, knowing how to build from the command line is equally important to know.

#
#compile main.c and area.c produce an executable named z1scko
#

gcc -o z1scko main.c area.c #compile main.c and area.c produce an executeab

# run that program
./z1scko 
6.000000

# here , we only compile main.c, and as expected things don't go well
gcc -o z1scko main.c
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc8yHV69.o: in function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `areaRectangle'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status


hope this helps you on your journey.

Hello @ticktalk, thank's for your concise anwser ! That might be quite off subject, but which IDE do you use, if you don't use VSCode ?

hi @Z1scko, I don't tbh, if obliged to then codeblocks link (old and superceded by much more modern ides - VS being one of many), vim typically meets all my trivial needs, gdb, valgrind and various system utilities typical go to's if/when required

Alright, I'll check this out, thank's for your anwser :) @ticktalk
